# Retrieve collection of elements whose key is less than specified value in c#

Tags: c#, collections, ienumerable, concurrentdictionary

I have a dictionary which is
`ConcurrentDictionary<uint, Mensaje> mensajesEnviados = new ConcurrentDictionary<uint, Mensaje>();`

I want to retrieve all the objects Mensaje whose key value is less than a certain value, to iterate on them. How should I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried? `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>` is enumerable; have you tried simply enumerating it, filtering on elements with the key value as you want? Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly what you've tried. Explain what that code does and how that's different from what you want.

Comment: I had tried exactly what is on the answer below. I was missing the Select part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var value = 42u; //your certain value
foreach (var m in mensajesEnviados.Where(kvp => kvp.Key < value).Select(kvp => kvp.Value))
{
}
```